# Make sure an incoming JSON response conforms to a schema?

Tags: json, swift, validation, schema

I use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to interact with the server API via JSON requests/responses. I want to make sure server responds with some strictly formed payload to my requests.

How do I check that, for example, in `{"responseCode":15, "data":{"username":"maxpayne", "fullname":"Max Payne", "score":154, friends:["johndoe", "franksinatra"]}}`, `responseCode` is a number, `username` and `fullname` are strings, and `friends` is an array of strings?

I can do it manually for each response, but seems like it's going to be the most worthless time waste.

Alamofire has `.validate()` method but it is created for different purpose as what I see. I also had a look at [JSONSchemaSwift](https://github.com/kylef/JSONSchema.swift) which seems to be a right solution, but is not in active development.

As an alternative, it could be good to have a JSON deserializer which validates a response automatically and creates an object based on a Swift class I define.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late, but this came out `kylef/JSONSchema.swift`came out on github. It's a JSONSchema validator, simple and effective.